# How to Disable Camelcase Property convertion from .Net Web API 2 Owin Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

I Implemented an AngularJS Project. The Server Side I coded using .NET Web API (C#). I Enabled the **CORS** in the Web API by installing the NuGet Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
I'm doing Authentication using **Owin Auth** https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAuthorizeEmployee()
    {
        return new Employee()
            {
                EID = "EMP_1001",
                User = "Ram@gmail.com",
                Name = "Ram Kumar",
                Mobile_Number = "9999911111"
            };
    }
}
```

The Model Classes are

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile_Number { get; set; }
}
```

In AngularJS, I'm getting the response message as like

```
{
    "eID": "EMP_1001",
    "user": "EMP_1001",
    "name": "EMP_1001",
    "mobile_Number": "EMP_1001"
}
```

I don't need this Camelcase Formatting, I need what I have given.

My expecting Output should be

```
{
    "EID": "EMP_1001",
    "User": "EMP_1001",
    "Name": "EMP_1001",
    "Mobile_Number": "EMP_1001"
}
```

I'm getting this issue after Owin Implementation. Kindly assist me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following Formatter in your **WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
};
```

This will revert the Camel-Case Formatting to default.

```
ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
```